# Apache Syncope Installation on Windows - Issue

Tags: apache, installation, apache-syncope

As per the installation steps shown in the URL -
 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SYNCOPE/Install+Syncope+from+installer

I had followed the same exact steps but I am stuck at step 5. It's neither throwing warning or errors. the whole wizard is not responding.

[image]

I did install maven and configured the data source in my application server - Tomcat.

Any help or leads or suggestions to resolving this issue would help me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to install new version (Syncope 2.0.7) with old documentation (Syncope 1.2).
Please follow [Getting Start With Apache Syncope](https://syncope.apache.org/docs/getting-started.html) and make sure your **$CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml** looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <user username="manager" password="s3cret" roles="manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```